# How to find the range of a cannon ball?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A cannon is positioned with a direction of 60 degrees between the ground and itself. (Sorry, again, for my poor English. I hope you understood that sentence.).
The shooting velocity is $800{\text{m}\over \sec}$. What is its range?

I didn't really understand this question. Am I asked how further the cannon ball will go before it descends? Because if so, I should I find the highest point the cannon ball get? Should I do it by differentiating?

I would truly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: This is classical mechanics: what formula for this do you have?!

Comment: I am confused. 
I've learned so far about acceleration, velocity, gravity and how to find each one by differentiating and integrating. Maybe I need further information?

Comment: Of course you do need more! There are well known, basic formulas for this: initial velocity, some kind of air resistance (or without it), the elevation angle, etc. You must have been given these formulas...or you can find them googing in the net, of course.

Comment: Consider vertical and horizontal component separately. Equate time taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest model, you are working in two dimensions, with the system of equations:

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = -g \\
\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = 0 \\
y(0)=0,y'(0)=\sin(\theta) s \\
x(0)=0,x'(0)=\cos(\theta) s
$$

where $g>0$ is acceleration due to gravity, $\theta$ is the angle of the initial velocity, and $s$ is the initial speed. Note that this model assumes no friction. When you solve you find

$$y(t)=-\frac{1}{2} gt^2 + \sin(\theta) s t \\
x(t)=\cos(\theta) s t.$$

Now the range of the ball is the horizontal distance it travels before hitting the ground, i.e. the value of $x$ when $y=0$. Can you find this using these equations?

Comment: I doubt whether differential equations will be helpful to the OP in this basic case. Also, something seems to be off, as using the formula $$r=\frac{v_0^2\sin 2\theta}g$$ with $\;r=$ range, $\;\theta\;$ elevation angle, $\;v_0=$ initial velocity  and $\;g=$ gravity's acceleration, I get $$r=\frac{800^2\sin 120^\circ}{9.8} =56,556.76$$ which seems to be half of what your equations give...but of course, I could be wrong: long time haven't done physics.

Comment: @Timbuc Note the comment where he mentioned doing these problems with integration of acceleration and velocity. Also, I think the $2$ that you are thinking is missing the $2$ in $\sin(2 \theta)=2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Yes, I know that trigonometric identity, yet solving your equations at the end I get half the correct (?) value.

Comment: @Timbuc Well, the equations of motion are definitely correct. Now the time of flight is $2 \frac{\sin(\theta) s}{g}$, so the range is $2 \frac{\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) s^2}{g} = \frac{\sin(2 \theta) s^2}{g}$. So I appear to have the same answer as the formula you quoted. Did you perhaps divide by $g$ instead of $g/2$ in finding the time of flight?

Comment: I really don't remember. it doesn't matter, though. Thanks.

Comment: It took me a while, but Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In projectile motion, you need to concern yourself with the two components of displacement:

$$x=x_0 + v_x t + \frac{1}{2}a_x t^2$$
$$y=y_0 + v_y t + \frac{1}{2}a_y t^2$$

If we place the cannon at the origin, then $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$. Furthermore, there is no acceleration in the $x$ direction if we neglect things like air resistance. Then $a_x = 0$. The acceleration in the $y$ direction is due to gravity $a_y = -g$.

$$x=v_x t$$
$$y=v_y t - \frac{1}{2}g t^2$$

We need to find the range. That is, we need to find the displacement in $x$ that occurs when the cannonball hits the ground, or when $y=0$.

$$x=v_x t$$
$$0=v_y t - \frac{1}{2}g t^2$$

The velocity can be broken up into components with trigonometry.

$$v_x = 800\cos60^\circ m/s$$
$$v_y = 800\sin60^\circ m/s$$

Using this information, solve for $t$ when the cannonball hits the ground. Then use that time to calculate displacement in $x$.